# Согласование во множественном числе

Tags: согласование

В сложившейся в настоящее время международной ситуации очень остро встает вопрос о замещении импортных арматуры и приводов на отечественные.

Правильно ли здесь слово "импортных" поставлено во множественном числе?

Также и здесь (слово "требуемых"):

Программный комплекс допускает изменение математических моделей типовых элементов и их связей без изменения шаблона расчетной схемы, что обеспечивает возможность расчета заданного регулятора давления по модели требуемых для конкретной задачи точности и сложности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) В сложившейся в настоящее время международной ситуации очень остро встает вопрос о замещении ИМПОРТНЫХ арматуры и приводов на отечественные.

В техническом тексте, а особенно в данном случае,  желательна смысловая точность, так как надо показать, что определение относится к обоим существительным.

(2)Программный комплекс допускает изменение математических моделей типовых элементов и их связей без изменения шаблона расчетной схемы, что обеспечивает возможность расчета заданного регулятора давления по модели ТРЕБУЕМОЙ для конкретной задачи точности  и 
сложности (или как вариант: по модели, имеющей ТРЕБУЕМУЮ для конкретной задачи точность  и сложность).

Здесь можно использовать единственное число, что определяется следующими факторами: соединительный союз И, тематическое сходство существительных точность и сложность, нет необходимости в смысловой точности сочетания прилагательного и двух существительных. Но мн.число  также возможно, что связано с техническим характером текста.